# WFFM Email Editor Buttons - Where did they go?

Tags: wffm

When I open the Send Email Save Action, the toolbar of the email editor is empty. Is this a config? Did I break it with a patch? Is that customizable?

**UPDATE 10/11**

In the console I get a whole bunch of these:

```
jsnlog.min.js:1 : {"stack":"Script error. \n at :undefined:undefined","message":"Script error.","logData":"Script error."}i.cerror @ jsnlog.min.js:1
Application.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of null
```

WFFM Version: 8.1 rev. 160304
Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160304

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot? I had some issues with `Send Email Action` fields in the past but I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: Is this on new forms or just existing?

Comment: Could you also update your question with WFFM version number

Comment: Also would be helpful to know Sitecore version.

Comment: Please take a look if you have any errors in the browser console. If there are errors, include them in your question.

Comment: Post updated with errors from console, Sitecore version and WFFM version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, WFFM's email editor is really just an RTE field. If your toolbar is missing, but your errors are not related to the issue (doesn't look like they are) then the issue is likely with your Html Editor Profi.e

Start by verifying that all of the items that should be there are present for the Rich Text Mail profile that is included with WFFM. This profile should be installed at the path */sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Mail*, in the Core database.

There are two ways that you can compare what you find in the Core database with what comes with WFFM:

1. Install the same version of WFFM on a clean Sitecore instance and compare
2. Download a fresh copy of WFFM, unzip and go into the *items/core* folder. From there, you can drill down until you find all of the serialized items that you should see in Sitecore. *(This route is quicker, but it is easier to miss things)*

I have seen similar issues with missing buttons before on projects using TDS/Unicorn, after items in the Rich Text Mail profile have been accidentally deleted from the project.